# How does dependency resolution work if you apt-get install a list of packages?

Tags: apt, package-management

Does `apt-get` automatically resolve dependencies if you `apt-get install` a literal list of packages?  I understand the default behavior of a command like `apt-get install foo` is to install the latest version of `foo`.  However, if I do:

```
sudo apt-get install foo bar
```

... and assume that `foo` depends on version `2.0` of `bar`, while the latest version of `bar` is `3.0`.  Is `apt-get` smart enough to install the latest version of `foo` and version `2.0` of `bar`, or will it fail as it can't resolve the dependencies?

Comment: Nope. This is a problem for some custom packages. You have to use apt pinning or specify the version in the installation command.

Comment: Is the dependency on bar =2.0, =>2.0 or <=2.0?